# Galaxy Fold Cover Screen

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

I would like to display content (while phone is unfolded) on secondary cover screen, as it is for built-in camera app.
Where you can set up an additional preview on the cover screen.

For the moment, I am able to get the secondary screen from DisplayManager:

```
        val displayManager = this.getSystemService(DISPLAY_SERVICE) as DisplayManager
        val display = displayManager.getDisplay(0)
```

Which displays correct resolution and looks like **isActivityStartAllowedOnDisplay** returns true.

Content of new intent is started without any errors"

```
val options = ActivityOptions.makeBasic()

options.launchDisplayId = display.getDisplayId()
val intent = Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java)

startActivity(intent, options.toBundle())
```

Unfortunatelly **display.state** is set to off.

In addition, "presentation" to second screen is also not working.

How can I enable cover display and start new activity on mentioned screen?

Answer (score 0):

Currently API responsible for this is not available for the 3rd party apps at the moment...